# How to Convert Query from PHP-MySQL to Node.js with Mysql and return value

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, object

I want to select data from mysql and put the value into object.

It's working on php but I didn't understand why is not worked in node.js

Note: I put only part of the codes.

mycode in php:

```
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT message FROM mempool messageID=1");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

$test = new BlockChain();

$test->addBlock(new Block($row['message']));
```

code in node.js

```
con.query("SELECT message FROM mempool where messageID=1", function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
let test = new Blockchain();
test.addBlock(rows);
```

the Error with node.js:

```
ReferenceError: rows is not defined
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in nodejs you use callback function, and row variable is not defined outside scope. if you will change it to

```
con.query("SELECT message FROM mempool where messageID=1", function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(rows);
    let test = new Blockchain();
    test.addBlock(rows);
    console.log(test);
  });
```

you can rewrite it to async/await way

```
const rows = await db.query( 'SELECT message FROM mempool where messageID=1' );
let test = new Blockchain();
test.addBlock(rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example might be useful [db select nodejs example](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/shownodejs_cmd.asp?filename=demo_db_select)

Problem is scope of the rows as mentioned above which should be inside con.query(....);